# Plotting certain bars in a series and groupnig the rest in one bar

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Imagine I have the series with the column that has various different values such as:

```
COL1    FREQUENCY
A       30
B       20
C       50
D       10
E       15
F       5
```

And I want to use matplotlib.pyplot to plot a bar graph that would display the number values A, B, C, and OTHERS, appearing in the series. I managed to do so without the 'others' grouping by simply doing this:

```
ax = srs.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

or

```
plt.bar(srs.index, srs)
```

And I know it shows all bar plots, how do I limit this to just show bars for A, B, C, and OTHERS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `map` then `groupby.sum()`:

```
s = df['COL1'].map(lambda x: x if x in ('A','B','C') else 'OTHERS')
to_plot = df.FREQUENCY.groupby(s).sum()
to_plot.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new dataframe and plot it afterwards

```
# list all values you want to keep
col1_to_keep = ['A','B','C']
# create a new dataframe with only these values in COL1
srs2 = srs.loc[srs['COL1'].isin(col1_to_keep)]
# create a third dataframe with only what you dont want to keep
srs3 = srs.loc[~srs['COL1'].isin(col1_to_keep)]
# create a dataframe with only one row containing the sum of frequency
rest = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':["OTHER"],'FREQUENCY': srs3['FREQUENCY'].sum()})
# add this row to srs2
srs2 =srs2.append(rest)
# you can finally plot it
ax = srs2.plot.bar(rot=0)
```